# Rendering React variables inside JSX, specifically how to 'tokenize' React Router structures? Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

**Problem:**

I'm following the React Router basic routing 
[quickstart guide](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start)
using their exact template inside a brand new `create-react-app` setup, replacing the default App.js with the following demo:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/about">About</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/users">Users</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        {/* A <Switch> looks through its children <Route>s and
            renders the first one that matches the current URL. */}
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/users">
            <Users />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

function Home() {
  return <h2>Home</h2>;
}

function About() {
  return <h2>About</h2>;
}

function Users() {
  return <h2>Users</h2>;
}
```

...which works as expected, however I want to work out how to 'tokenize' the Route paths - currently 'About', 'Users' and 'Home'.

---

**Challenge:**

I created a ./tokens.js file containing the following:

```
export default {
    one: 'one',
    two: 'two',
    three: 'three'
};
```

...and can successfully inject these sample token values into the JSX(?) in certain places, but either can't or simply can't work out *how* to do it in others.

For example, the following works:

```
<Link to="/">{tokens.one}</Link>
```

...which allows me to dynamically change the link values via tokens.js.

but I still can't quite consolidate everything into single token changes because I still have structures like the following that would need to be renamed manually/individually:

```
<Switch>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/users">
            <Users />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
```

...wherein I can't see any way to change the ,  etc. into token.vals

as well as

```
function Home(){}
function About(){}
```

etc. where the function names are similarly 'fixed', so how would I ensure all instances of 'Home' in the supplied demo could could all be uniformly linked to a single token variable?

**What are my options here?**

---

**Background:** UI/UX Designer with little hands on web dev experience, very green with React and there's a high likelihood the answer to this is that I'm trying to do something silly, rather than the issue being what is/isn't possible. Open to all answers.

Comment: the answer I posted wrong had a slight syntax mistake, I fixed it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a structure like this:

```
export default [{path: '/about', component: About},{path: '/users', component: Users}];
```

And then do

```
{tokens.map(t => (
    <Route path={t.path}> <t.component /> </Route>
))}
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is very clear and works like a charm. Exactly the logic I was looking for.

My only outstanding question is that since React Router ties the <component /> name to the function name to be called afterwards, how do I ensure the name of the functions like: `function About() {
  return <h2>About</h2>;
}` maintain the convention we have just established?

Comment: To add some further confusion, even when hardcoding the function names below after succesfully using your solution - ie `function One(){return <h2>Hello</h2>}`, I cannot invoke anything.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking for and what you want to happen.